# How to change a form's target to in-app browser in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic framework to build an android app.

I have a form as such:

```
<form action='https://secure.payu.in/_payment' method="POST" target="...">
  ......
</form>
```

Is there a way to change the form's target to an instance of a cordova in-app broswer?

I have tried "_blank" but that disconnects my app from the web-view.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find thus far was making use of iframes.

I give the name of an iframe in the target attribute in the form.

```
<form action='https://secure.payu.in/_payment' method="POST" target="iframe">
  ......
</form>

<iframe name="iframe"></iframe>
```

However this causes concerns of security.